# How to verify multiple values with xpath or store a value

Tags: xpath

My xpath expression is as follows:

```
//ep:getSwitchListResponse[1]/result[1]/item[position() >1 and position() <= last()]/ipAddress[1]/text()
```

I want to get the value of `position()` and use it to verify the name . something like

```
//ep:getSwitchListResponse[1]/result[1]/**item[Position()FromPreviousQuery**)]/name[1]/text()
```

Is this possible to do both in one xpath expression?

Comment: Please post the xml you're targeting with an example of what you'd like returned. That being said, you could plug in the first XPath expression **as** the position, to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you store the position from the first XPath somewhere locally, you'll have to recall the xpath again if you want to reuse the same position, XPath doesn't store anything from previous traversals.

Ex)

Your first xpath:

```
//ep:getSwitchListResponse[1]/result[1]/item[position() >1 and position() <= last()]/ipAddress[1]/text()
```

Its position:

```
count(//ep:getSwitchListResponse[1]/result[1]/item[position() >1 and position() <= last()]/ipAddress[1]/preceding-sibling::*)
```

The position XPath plugged into the second:

```
//ep:getSwitchListResponse[1]/result[1]/**item[count(//ep:getSwitchListResponse[1]/result[1]/item[position() >1 and position() <= last()]/ipAddress[1]/preceding-sibling::*)]/name[1]/text()
```